# Look for a second value (range) based on a first lookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to get the commission on column D based on two inputs, column F2, and the sales range entered on column F3 which will look at the range between B and C and return D. We have around 200 Employees and 10 different commission ranges.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,G2)-1),MATCH(G3,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,G2)-1)))
```

[image]

Or:

```
=INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(D2:D7)/((A2:A7=G2)*(B2:B7<=G3)*(C2:C7>=G3)),1))
```

[image]

Or:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G2,B:B,"<="&G3,C:C,">=" & G3)
```

[image]

Use the last if the values returned are numbers and not a string.

Use the second if your values to return are strings and the data set is relatively small.

Use the first if none of the above.